# Fix font and font size in android application

Tags: java, android, css, fonts

Is there anyway to fix my font and font size for my android application?
I wanted to prevent people to change my application font even if they have installed app like bytafont.
I really have no idea what to do to fix it as the results that I have search are all about how to change the font but not fixing the font.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you a different perspective here: why do you want do that?

If some of your users are so **unhappy** with the fonts that your App is using that they get into the business of installing other Apps in order to manipulate that; who are you to prevent them from doing that?

In other words: even if it is technical possible: consider not doing this. As an App developer, your goal is to **attract** users; not to **annoy** them!

EDIT: as you say you are worried that changing fonts could affect the responsiveness/usability of your App - don't assume. Make experiments to see what happens! Maybe it is not such a problem at all!

And even if it is: users have **override** things to get there. In other words, coming from the business perspective: is it worth spending your time on this?

Maybe 0.1% of your users manipulate fonts; and and afterwards 50% of those people are unhappy with your App. Is it worth spending efforts for that small group at all? Versus: simply working on other, great features that attract more customers? Your development time is a limited resource; so you have to be careful what you are spending it for!

Comment: for your information, I am doing so because I scare that my layout is not responsive enough to handle different font and different size.

Comment: oh well. i will try to talk to my senior as this is the task that my senior pass it to me which i think it is not possible to be done.

Comment: Please note: I am not saying that this technically impossible. I am just trying to give you a different *perspective* on this task. It could still be the reasonable thing to technically solve this. But typically, it doesn't hurt to consider things from more than one point of view.